# How do I execute the following command using subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I want to execute the following command using subprocess:

```
sudo sh -c "echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 > /etc/resolv.conf"
```

In the shell it does work well.

This is what I did:

```
update_resolv_conf_cmd = (["sudo", "sh", "-c", '"echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 > /etc/resolv.conf"'])
subprocess.Popen(update_resolv_conf_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work out

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("sudo sh -c 'echo nameserver 1.1.1.1 > /etc/resolv.conf'", shell=True)
```

Comment: Yes this does the job. Thanks. This subprocess module is somewhat weird.